# addslashes() for preg_replace() and co.?

Tags: php, regex

How can I escape incoming data so I can use it as a pattern in `preg_replace()` and consorts? For example, I need to match against this string:

```
/vorschau/
```

Obviously, I need to escape the "v" or I will get an error.

I can't find anything in the documentation. Is there some sort of `addslashes()` for this, or a workaround within the expression?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote) :

```
string preg_quote  ( string $str  [, string $delimiter = NULL  ] )
```

> `preg_quote()` takes `str`  and puts a
>   backslash in front of every character
>   that is part of the regular expression
>   syntax. 
> This is useful if you have
>   a run-time string that you need to
>   match in some text and the string may
>   contain special regex characters.
>
> The special regular expression
>   characters are: `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( )
>   { } = ! < > | : -`

Comment: That's exactly what I looked for and didn't know about. Thanks!

Comment: @Pekka : you're welcome :-)  (I hate when I see code in which some one re-invented to whell and tried to re-code this function, actually ^^ )

Answer (score 0):

It does seem that you want `preg_quote`, but perhaps you should detail your situation more, because it’s quite possible that what you are trying to do could be done a better way.

Comment: preg_quote() it is. I need to remove a base directory from the request URI: e.g. removing `/mydirectory` from `/mydirectory/xyz/123` = results in `/xyz/123`, and `preg_replace()` looks like the most elegant way to do it. If you have a better solution fire away!

Comment: `$stripped = substr($fullpath, strlen($basedir));`

Comment: Regex is great, but rarely the best solution to simple string manipulation like that :)